# Text messaging Force Close issues after OS upgrade

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-galaxy-s, sms

I upgraded my Samsung Galaxy S GT I 9000 to Android 2.2 yesterday...but I just can't open my messages...it says Force Close every time I try...any solutions??

If not, how can I downgrade to the original 2.1 Eclair?

Answer (score 2):

Try clearing the cache of the Messaging app.

From the home screen:

`Menu | Settings | Applications | Manage applications | All | Messaging | Clear cache`

If that doesn't work, I'd try the following, in this order:

1. Force Stop
2. Restart the phone (off then on)
3. Clear data (will likely lose your SMS messages)

Comment: how do i do dat? :(

Comment: d messagin app doesnt hav clear cache option highlighted..so can't select it...

Comment: Well, you can try "Clear data" but that will probably dump all of your messages. Have you power-cycled the phone?

Comment: wats power-cycle? ive no idea how to do dat

Comment: Turn the device off then turn it back on.

Comment: nope not working...stil force closes..i can't even receive messages now

Comment: You should try the Clear Data option, then. The good news is is that won't lose your messages. (I just did it on my Droid.)

Comment: tried dat too.. not working..stil can't c messages..how do i put back 2.1 in my fone?

Comment: You'd have to root it. Your best bet now is to get in touch with tech support at your carrier.

Comment: A last final resort would be to do a factory reset of the phone.  You would, however, lose all data and applications in the process.